# How to fix "Unsupported Schema format for unwrapping! found all but expected sequence" in cfinvoke CF11?

Tags: web-services, coldfusion-11, cfinvoke

I'm running into an odd issue when invoking a webservice from the cfinvoke tag on ColdFusion 11 Enterprise Edition. The error message I am getting is:

> Unsupported Schema format for unwrapping! found all but expected
>   sequence

The stack trace starts with:

> org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationException: Unsupported
>   Schema format for unwrapping! found all but expected sequence at
>   org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.extension.SchemaUnwrapperExtension.processXMLSchemaSequence(SchemaUnwrapperExtension.java:405)
>   at...

Has anyone else encountered this issue or know how to fix it? A big thank you in advance for any help or advice.

Comment: Is the web service using Axis2?  Have you tried using Axis1 instead?

Comment: The webservice is using Axis1. (I only found that after some hours of debugging). So I've needed to use the wsversion attribute and set it to 1.

But now I encounter another error "faultString: [Virtuoso SOAP server] There is no such procedure". I've passed all correct arguments with <cfinvokeargument tags to the method I'm calling

Comment: it's probably best to include that as an answer to this question and then open another question (if you want to) for the new issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that I had this issue is that the web service is using Axis1. ColdFusion 11 by default assumes that the web service is using Axis2.

To fix it, I've added the `wsversion` attribute to the `<cfinvoke>` tag and set its value to 1.